# Was ist das „Das(s)“ für ein Ding: „Was du nicht willst, das(s) man dir tu“?

Tags: spelling, conjunction

Bei der Lektüre eines Buchs überraschte mich, dass der bekannte ethische Grundsatz aus der Lutherbibel „Was du nicht willst, dass man dir tu’, das füg’ auch keinem anderen zu“ mit einem *Dass* mit Doppel-S geschrieben ist. Tatsächlich funktioniert er ebenso – so hatte ich ihn auch immer verstanden – mit einem *Das* mit einfachem S.

Die – recht ähnlichen – Bedeutungen wären

> Doppel-S: Was du nicht willst, dass man es dir antut     (*dass* als Konjunktion)

versus

> Einfach-S: Was du nicht willst, *welches* man dir antut 
>                  (*das* bezieht sich auf *was*)

Was ist nun „richtig“?

Oft hilft es, die „Masse zu fragen“, zum Beispiel nach beiden Varianten zu googeln und die Anzahl der Treffer zu vergleichen. Das Ergebnis im vorliegenden Fall ist recht überraschend und bezeichnend: [572.000](http://www.google.de/search?q=%22Was%20du%20nicht%20willst%20dass%20man%20dir%20tu%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:de:official&client=firefox-a&source=hp&channel=np) Treffer für Doppel-S, [579.000](http://www.google.de/#sclient=psy-ab&hl=de&source=hp&q=%22Was+du+nicht+willst+das+man+dir+tu%22&pbx=1&oq=%22Was+du+nicht+willst+das+man+dir+tu%22&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=14305l14305l1l14454l1l1l0l0l0l0l0l0ll0l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.,cf.osb&fp=f3659ec7e2068da0&biw=1680&bih=898) für das einfache. Auch die Kombination mit Lutherbibel liefert unklare Resultate.

Weiß jemand mehr?

Comment: Ich halte die Variante mit doppel-s für einen Fehler. Ich lehne mich weit aus dem Fenster und wage zu behaupten, dass nur die allerwenigsten der "dass"-Schreiber an die von Dir vorgebrachte Begründung dachten. Die meisten dachten wohl: "Da ist ein Komma, da kommt dass mit doppel-s".

Comment: @fzwo: `...da kommt ''das'' dass mit ...` - soviel Zeit muss sein!

Comment: `Oft hilft es, die "Masse zu fragen"` - ist wohl nicht richtig. Da, wo die Masse richtig liegt, liegt man selbst auch eher richtig, und wenn die Masse irrt, dann hilft es einem also nicht. Qualität != Quantität.

Comment: Zwingender Kommentar: `Was Du nicht willst, das man Dir tu, das willst Du doch, was willst denn Du?` (Otto Walkes, 70er Jahre)

Comment: Zwingende Korrektur:  Was du nicht willst, dass man dir will, das willst du kei'm, was willst denn du?! -- Otto *Waalkes* (Hervorhebungen von mir)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### Relativsatz

Immer, wenn man den Nebensatz auch mit *welches* oder *was* bilden kann, kommt ein Relativsatz in Betracht.

Ursprünglich hatte Luther in seiner Bibelübersetzung von 1545 im Buch Tobit 4 folgenden Satz geschrieben:

[image]

<sup>Quelle: [Google Books](http://books.google.com/books?id=6ZLaAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA1738&img=1&pgis=1&dq=was%20du%20wilt&sig=ACfU3U1Eg4z2hq9q7Hwf8SbHsMfKaZQ4ig&edge=0)</sup>

Erst später ist durch die doppelte Verneinung ein gereimtes Sprichwort entstanden:

> Was du nicht willst, das man dir tu’, das füg’ auch keinem andern zu.

Hier steht *das* in Relation zu *was* (wie im Satz *Was in der Bibel steht, das glaube ich*) als [Relativpronomen](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/dass) und wird somit mit nur einem *s* geschrieben.

---

### Unterordnende Konjunktion

Natürlich kann man die Goldene Regel auch mit Hilfe einer untergeordneten Konjunktion bilden:

> Was du nicht willst, dass man dir tu’, das füg’ auch keinem andern zu.

---

### Was ist nun „richtig“?

Beide Formen sind grammatikalisch richtig und haben fast dieselbe Bedeutung. Für welche Form man sich entscheidet hängt davon ab, ob man mit einer unterordnenden Konjunktion die Handlung (das *Tun*) in den Vordergrund rücken möchte, oder ob man einen Relativsatz bilden möchte, der die Betonung auf das Ergebnis (das *Was*) richtet.

Wie man in der [schönen Antwort zur Übersetzung aus dem griechischen Original](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/7016/23) sehen kann, sind unter Zuhilfenahme auch der anderen Evangelien beide Interpretationen möglich. Man bewegt sich dann auf kompliziertem und hier zu weit führendem theologischen Grund.

Die der Wendung zu Grunde liegende Übersetzung von Luther legt allerdings einen Relativsatz nahe.

Comment: Reichlich spät, aber durch den "Bump" mir erst jetzt aufgefallen: Bist Du sicher? Dein Beispiel in der Klammer wird erst durch einen Zusatz wirklich zur analogen Konstruktion: "Was in der Bibel steht, *dass man tun soll,* das glaube ich" - und das funktioniert eben nicht als Relativpronomen. Die Stelle aus Google Books würde ich nicht zwingend als Beleg für eine bestimmte, heute regelkonforme Schreibung sehen :)

Comment: @Mac: siehe Edit ;) Man könnte darüber wahrscheinlich ein Buch schreiben.

Answer (score 8):

Ich stimme dem zu, was schon in der Frage vorweggenommen ist: Beide Interpretationen, und damit beide Schreibweisen, wären denkbar. Der einzige Weg, es wirklich sicher herauszufinden: Zeitmaschine nehmen, Luther persönlich fragen. :-) Aber vielleicht gibt es noch einen anderen Weg, es zumindest einzugrenzen.

---

Die Deutsche Bibelgesellschaft hat den [Text von verschiedenen Bibelausgaben](http://www.bibelwissenschaft.de/online-bibeln/) ins Netz gestellt. Dem kann man entnehmen, daß die moderne Lutherbibel (Fassung von 1984) *daß/dass* benutzt, und zwar sowohl in *Tobit 4,16* (andere Bibelausgaben zählen es als Vers *15*) als auch an der davon abgeleiteten, positiv formulierten Stelle *Matthäus 7,12*:

> Was du nicht willst, dass man dir tu, das füg auch keinem andern zu.
>
> Alles nun, was ihr wollt, dass euch die Leute tun sollen, das tut ihnen auch!

Diese Konstruktion ist eine Spezialität der Lutherbibel. Andere Bibelübersetzungen formulieren die Tobit-Stelle ganz anders:

> Was du selbst nicht erleiden möchtest, das füge auch keinem anderen zu! (Gute-Nachricht-Bibel)
>
> Tue niemandem, was dir selbst widerwärtig ist. (Menge-Bibel)
>
> Was dir selbst verhaßt ist, das mute auch einem anderen nicht zu! (Einheitsübersetzung)

(Alle Zitate nach den oben verlinkten „Online-Bibeln“, ausgenommen das aus der Einheitsübersetzung – dieses nach einer mir vorliegenden Papierausgabe.)

Das läßt schon vermuten, daß Luther eher frei übersetzt und die Konstruktion nicht aus dem Originaltext nachgebaut hat. Und in der Tat, die AT-Stelle lautet in der Septuaginta einfach:

> καὶ ὃ μισεῖς, μηδενὶ ποιήσῃς.
>
> Und (das), das du haßt, sollst du niemandem tun.

(Meine möglichst wörtliche Übersetzung.)

Die letzte Chance also: das Matthäus-Evangelium. Hier ist es etwas umständlicher formuliert:

> Πάντα οὖν ὅσα ἐὰν θέλητε ἵνα ποιῶσιν ὑμῖν οἱ ἄνθρωποι, οὕτως καὶ ὑμεῖς ποιεῖτε αὐτοῖς.
>
> Alles also, von dem ihr womöglich wollt, daß die Menschen (es) euch tun: so tuet auch ihr ihnen.

Aha. Das sieht dem Luthertext doch viel ähnlicher; und hier ist es eindeutig die Wiedergabe einer griechischen Konjunktion (ἵνα).

---

Nun hatte Takkat in [seiner/ihrer Antwort](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/2986/#answer-2987) den ursprünglichen Text Luthers von 1545 für *Tobit 4,16* wiedergegeben:

> Was du wilt das man dir thue / das thu einem andern auch.

Wie man sieht, ist es positiv formuliert wie im Matthäus-Evangelium, nicht negativ wie an der Stelle, die er angeblich übersetzt (und wie in den modernen Bibelausgaben). Deshalb halte ich es für plausibel, daß Luther sich hier von *Matthäus 7,12* hat beeinflussen lassen. Dann dürfte das „das(s)“, das hier in Rede steht, die Entsprechung zur griechischen Konjunktion ἵνα und damit wohl ebenfalls als Konjunktion gemeint sein.

Die moderne Lutherbibel hat somit recht, was die Orthographie angeht. Sehr nah am griechischen Originaltext des Buchs Tobit ist sie aber nicht gerade.

Comment: Bei dem ganzen Streit um das eine 's' geht völlig die viel interessantere Tatsache unter, daß die negativ formulierte Regel einen völlig anderen ethischen Gehalt hat als die positiv formulierte.

Answer (score 3):

> Die Verbindung zwischen einem Hauptsatz und einem Relativsatz hat keine eigentliche Bedeutung. Relativsätze sind Attributsätze, das heißt Nebensätze, die sich auf ein Nomen (oder seltener ein Pronomen) im Hauptsatz beziehen und dieses näher bestimmen.

Darum handelt es sich hier nicht. Es gibt kein Nomen im Hauptsatz, auf das sich „das man dir tu“ bezieht. Selbst wenn der Nebensatz „Was du nicht willst“ als Ersatz für ein Nomen angesehen würde, klappt es nicht. Stellen wir uns vor, wir nehmen statt dieses Nebensatzes ein Nomen, dann könnte es etwa heißen:

> Das Ungewollte, das man dir tu …

Das geht nicht. Es passt auch nicht zu einem Relativsatz, dass er im Konjunktiv steht. Er beschreibt doch nur. Nein, das *dass* rührt her von der Verbindung „ich will nicht, dass …“ Und da macht dann auch der Konjunktiv Sinn, da das Gesagte eben nicht Realität werden soll. Luther kann mit seiner Rechtschreibung kein Maßstab für uns sein, in seiner Zeit schrieb man doch sowieso alles anders. Also kann es nur so geschrieben werden:

> Was du nicht willst, dass man dir tu, das füg auch keinem andern zu!

Comment: Servus und Willkommen beim Stackexchange der deutschen Sprache. Nimm eine [tour] der Seite und befrage das [help], wenn du mehr darüber wissen möchtest, wie sie funktioniert. Da deine Antwort als einziger langer Absatz etwas schwer lesbar war, habe ich sie ein bisschen auseinandergezogen. Falls dir das nicht gefallen hat, oder du sonstiges verbessern möchtest, gibt es unter dem Post links einen *edit*-Knopf.

Answer (score 0):

Was du nicht willst, dass (eigentlich: man es dir tue). Also eine Konjunktion, also nur dass.

Answer (score 0):

Entweder: "Wenn du nicht willst, dass man dir ETWAS (Bestimmtes) antut, dann füge (genau) DAS auch keinem anderen zu."

oder sinngemäß: "DAS (Übel), von dem du nicht willst, dass man ES (das Übel) dir antut, DAS (Übel) füge auch keinem anderen zu."

oder sinngemäß: "WAS du nicht willst, DAS man dir tu, DAS füg auch keinem andern zu."

oder aber "WAS du nicht willst, DASS man ES dir tu, DAS füg auch keinem andern zu."

Answer (score -2):

Eindeutig "das"

Die Begründung kann auch nicht in den fremdsprachlichen Urtexten liegen, auf die sich dieser Ausspruch nicht exakt bezieht. Da könnte man höchsten über den Sinn der Verneinung diskutieren.

Nein - man soll doch bitte diesen Satz aussprechen. Wer "das" betont, muss es auch so schreiben.